# Checkbox within jQuery dialog firing change event but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a div (wrapper) to generate a form on the fly :

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Then I fill it up in the javascript and turn it into a dialog that display some information and a checkbox list

```
<div id="formulaire" title="Insérer un nouvel utilisateur">
    <p>Remplir le fomrulaire suivant :</p>
    <label for="user" style="display:inline-block;width:130px;">Utilisateur (WF) : </label><span id="nom"></span><br />
    <label for="mail" style="display:inline-block;width:130px;">Adresse E-mail : </label><span id="prenom"></span><br /><br />
    <label for="permission">L'utilisateur a les permissions suivantes : </label><br />

<ol>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" /> Gérer la fréquence des visites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" /> Chercher un client sur le serveur</li>
    <ul><li id="Li1"><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" />Télécharger ce client</li></ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" /> Proposer un prix inférieur au prix minium</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox5" /> Créer des &quot;Price Credit Note&quot;</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox6" /> Créer des &quot;Quote Approval&quot;</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox7" /> Créer des &quot;Price Afreement&quot;</li>
</ol>

    <input type="button" value="Valider"/>
</div>
```

with the following javascript :

```
function CreateUser(nom, prenom){
    $("#wrapper").empty();
    $("#wrapper").append()//Here I append the html above

    $("#nom").text(nom);
    $("#prenom").text(prenom);
    $("#Li1").hide();

    $("#Checkbox2").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#Li1").show()
        }
        else {
            $("#Li1").hide()
        }
    });

    $("#formulaire").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 450
    });
}
```

This function is called by a button, The dialog shows up properly but I want the 3rd element (which is a sub list) on the list to appear only if Checkbox2 is checked. The issue is that even though the change event fires, if I close the dialog and open a new one, #Li1 no longer shows or hide, nothing happens when I check/uncheck Checkbox2. Where does the issue come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this**    keyword represent the current object. as you are using jQuery callback it is better to use it in following manner...

```
$("#Checkbox2").change(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                $("#Li1").show()
            }
            else {
                $("#Li1").hide()
            }
        });
```

You can also check for checkbox in following manner

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Thanks for the details of step you followed to reproduce this problem.
This is better to destroy the dialog so jQuery take proper care of underlying elements as well as associated events. Hence destroy the dialog properly and use `$(this)` to access source element in event.

Comment: Tried it, the event fire (verified with an alert("test")) but Li1 doesnt show or hide, nothing happens

Comment: In that case add a callback function to show() call and try to debug if it is getting invoked properly. If it still doesn't works, then check the CSS properties if any property is restricting the element to set 'display' property to 'none'

Comment: I added a function that jsut alert("test") and put it as callback of both show and hdie and to my big surprise, both time its is called. does that mean that somehow Li1 does not exist at a give time when it should ?

Comment: make one thing first. rather than binding the Change event, bind Click event so i will get called just once and not twice. Check the result after this change

Comment: When using Click the result is pretty much the same as change. I open the form (dialog) > I check Checkbox2 > Li1 shows > I uncheck > Li1 hide > I close/reopen the form > I check Checkbox2 > nothing happens > uncheck > nothing happens. I wrote 2 callback fonction (alert show and alert hide) to see if both function are called properly and they are, except that Li1 still not appears/disappears

Comment: The problem is... Each time you are showing a dialog and new elements are getting created again and again.. that is why first time it works properly and fails after that for each attempt. Make sure you are destroying your dialog properly on close.

Comment: Nice, adding a .dialog('destroy') on the dialogclsoe event worked. However I thought emptying the $("#wrapper") would be enough, if you know why it wasnt, could you include that in your edited answer ?